# kafka consumer not consuming from multiple topics when one is empty

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am experimenting with kafka streams. I want my `Kstream` to be reading out of multiple topics so I provided with an array of topics (2) to read from.

My producer on the other hand usually writes to one of those topics. When this is the case my consumer (`KStream`) is not consuming anything at all but when my producer is writing to both topics the consumer is reading messages from both.

It feels like a partitioning implication but I cannot pin down what exactly is the problem.

**update**

digging a bit deeper I can say that the problem is reproducible. I am using `confluent-3.2.0`. Additionally the consumer needs to be restarted after both topics have been subscribed in order to read the messages that have been pushed to the topics so far (I am using `auto.creation` of topics and don't subscribe them in advance).

Comment: This should work as expected... Can you reliably reproduce it? If yes, than this sounds like a bug. What version do you use? Also, did you pre-create all input topics before starting your Streams application?

Comment: I use kafka server version `0.10.1.0` and kafka streams version `0.10.2.0`.
I have enabled the `auto.create.topics.enable` option on the server so in the case when only one topic is used by the producer the second topic is not subscribed at all on the server, although the consumer is subscribed to it. Do you think this may be part of the issue?

Comment: btw I am using [this](https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka) docker image. I will try to reproduce with my local kafka version too

Comment: I can say with certainty that the problem is reproducible. locally I am using `confluent-3.2.0`. Should I open an issue?

Comment: I am not sure yet if it might be a bug or "user error". (1) it's not recommended to enable auto topic create (cf http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#user-topics) (2) We did fix a bug about meta data refresh recently -- can you try out Streams `0.10.2.1` (not officially release yet, but RC available at https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/

Comment: It could also be this one: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5037 But it only applies if all input topics are unknown at startup -- so I actually doubt it is the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps you want to consider trying with Confluent's docker images for Kafka, see https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could share the Kafka Streams related code that you are using (e.g., how you defined the KStream to read from multiple input topics).